# How to save data to database from browser in database - call python function

Tags: python, cherrypy

How to save data to database from browser, I have function which saves to database ( in python - cherrypy and I can collect easy data from form) and it works, but how to call this function on click event  ?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't completely understand the question.
But considering you have something like a checkbox in some CherryPy app,
you can pass the selected value forward as,

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cpu" value="host1" /> host1<br>
```

.....

```
class Root(object):
        @cherrypy.expose

    def default(self, **kwargs):
        if len(kwargs) > 0:
            print 'Metric to be collected and selected arguments:'
        print '''
Metric:  | Choosen arguments passed to remote script:  %s   |   %s''' %(target, selection)
```